# printing a struct prints out random paths

Tags: c, struct, printing, readfile

I'm trying to read a text file with details into a struct other when I try to print out the output of a struct, i just get met with random numbers or a

[image: weird address].

Can I please get some help where i am going wrong?

Tthe text file is set up as

```
4, 2, 10000
```

---

```
typedef struct
{
    int bed;
    int bath;
    int price;
}house;

int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    linkedList* list = createLinkedList();
 

    house sydney[4];
    int total;
    int ii;
    f = fopen("house", "r");

    fscanf(f, "%d", &total);
    for (ii = 0; ii < total; ii++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%d%d%d", &house[ii].bed, &house[ii].bath, &house[ii].price);
        printf("Price: %d", house[ii].price);
    }
```

Comment: You don't check if `fopen` succeeds. If the file cannot be opened for some reason, `fopen` returns `NULL` but you don't check that.

Comment: Also show a [mcve] that triggers the problem. Read this: [ask]

Comment: The commas in the input file are not matched with anything in the `scanf()` format string.

Comment: @pmg fscanf(f, "%d, %d, %d, .... )???

Comment: *Always* check what [`fscanf` (and related functions) ***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: But all the above aside, the code you show shouldn't print anything string-like! The code just doesn't match anything that would produce the output you claim. So as @Jabberwocky already told you: Please create a [mcve], then [edit] your question to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fscanf(f, "%d, %d, %d", &house[ii].bed, &house[ii].bath, &house[ii].price);
```

Also I would suggest to check the return value of fscanf to make sure all the parameters were found.

Comment: how would you check return value of the fscanf

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm "This function returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure."

Comment: @alicesmith `if (fscanf(f, .....) != 3) ....`